# Installing SQL Server 2012 Express fails with error " Could not find the Database Engine startup handle."

Tags: installation, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to install SQL Server Express 2012 w/ SP1 x64 on Windows 7 SP1 x64. This machine has previously had SQL Server Express 2012 installed. This instance was upgraded to SQL Server 2012 Standard, which has since been uninstalled.

Following are the options selected during the install:

- Include SQL Server product updates in install  -- 2 related to KB
  2793634
- Install all features to default directories
- Named instance SQLEXPRESS in default instance root directory
- Default services accounts:   SQL Server Database Engine -> NT
  Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
- Default Database Engine Configuration

The install fails with following error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%25400x4BDAF9BA%25401306%254025
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I've read that this may be related to a corrupt MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS virtual account.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Jon.

**Summary.txt**

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  Failed: see details
>   below   Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893607   Start time:
>   2014-03-24 12:08:49   End time:                      2014-03-24
>   12:28:21   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>   information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
>   the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this
>   feature, and then run the setup process again.   Next step for
>   Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error,
>   uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  MONTREAL
>   Machine processor count:       4   OS version:
>   Windows 7   OS service pack:               Service Pack 1   OS region:
>   United States   OS language:                   English (United States)
>   OS architecture:               x64   Process architecture:          64
>   Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2012 Service Pack 1   ProductName:                   SQL Server
>   2012   Type:                          RTM   Version:
>   11   Installation location:         c:\097a5adf24ea31e1a16d\x64\setup\
>   Installation edition:          Express
>
> Slipstream:                    True   SP Level
>   1   Patch Level:                   11.1.3128.0
>
> Product Update Status:   Success: KB 2674319, KB 2793634
>
> Product Updates Selected for Installation:   Title:
>   Service Pack 1   Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2674319   Version: 
>   11.1.3000.0   Architecture:                  x64   Language:                      1033
>
> Title:                         SQL Server 2012 SP1 GDR Product
>   Update   Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2793634   Version:
>   11.1.3128.0   Architecture:                  x64   Language:                      All
>
> Update Source:                 MU
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled   ASBACKUPDIR:
>   Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
>   Data   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:
>   1   ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>      ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTEMPDIR:
>   Temp   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CLTCTLRNAME:
>      CLTRESULTDIR:                     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                    CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>      CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:
>      CTLRSVCPASSWORD:                  CTLRUSERS:
>      ENABLERANU:                    true   ENU:
>   true   ERRORREPORTING:                false   FEATURES:
>   SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, SNAC_SDK   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
>   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:              FTSVCACCOUNT:
>      FTSVCPASSWORD:                    HELP:
>   false   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   false   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ 
>   INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS   INSTANCENAME:
>   SQLEXPRESS   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network
>   Service   ISSVCPASSWORD:                    ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:
>      MATRIXNAME:                       NPENABLED:
>   0   PID:                           *****   QUIET:
>   false   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:
>   AllFeatures_WithDefaults   RSINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultNativeMode   RSSHPINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultSharePointMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SAPWD:                            SECURITYMODE:
>      SQLBACKUPDIR:                     SQLCOLLATION:
>   Latin1_General_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT
>   Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                
>   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:
>   Montreal\Jonathan Bailey   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:                  SQLUSERDBDIR:
>      SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:                  SQMREPORTING:
>   false   TCPENABLED:                    0   UIMODE:
>   AutoAdvance   UpdateEnabled:                 true   UpdateSource:
>   MU   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140324_120228\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup
>   process of the feature.   Next Step:                     Use the
>   following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature,
>   and then run the setup process again.   Component name:
>   SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features   Component
>   error code:          0x851A0019   Error description:             Could
>   not find the Database Engine startup handle.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025
>
> Feature:                       SQL Server Replication   Status:
>   Failed: see logs for details   Reason for failure:            An error
>   occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for
>   the feature to fail.   Next Step:                     Use the
>   following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature,
>   and then run the setup process again.   Component name:
>   SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features   Component
>   error code:          0x851A0019   Error description:             Could
>   not find the Database Engine startup handle.   Error help link:
>   <>    > 
>     Feature:                       SQL Browser   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Writer   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK   Status:
>   Passed
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20140324_120228\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: No more guesses. You're going to locate and read the install log files. See [View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx). If you cannot identify the error yourself in the installation log, post the log here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After working with Microsoft Technical Support on this issue, we determined that the act of uninstalling SQL Server Standard and re-installing SQL Server Express leaves the service account (in this case, **NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS**) in a state in which it doesn't have the permissions needed to run the service.

To fix the problem, we manually went through and added the permissions required as specified in [Configure Windows Server Accounts and Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Serv_Perm) in the SQL Server documentation. Note that only some of the permissions were missing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that was the bloker for me too. Being unable to find out how to reconfigure those rights on NT service accounts on a windows 7 station (they are not showing up in account management, which anyway does not seem to allow configuring rights), I fix the trouble by suppressing those accounts profiles. (Computer properties, advanced parameters, user profile parameters, suppressing net service\mssql profiles, then go to users folder, suppressing their folders (had required taking ownerships, reboot, ...), and finally reinstalling.)

Answer (score 10):

A simple and complete solution to error ' Could not find database engine startup handle' in below link
**Reason for the error can be**

1.The account which user selected on Server Configuration page window ( during installation)  is somehow not able to bring SQL Server database engine services online. Either is lacks privilege or it is corrupted. During installation of database engine services SQL Server tries to bring online database services as a internal process but due to startup account either corrupt or not having appropriate privileges it fails to do so and ultimately installation fails.

2.Other reason is when installation fails first time due to some reason and user uninstall failed installation from add remove program, the un-installation leaves account in broken state so any further attempt to install flashes this error message

**Solution can be.**

Uninstall SQL server completely from Add remove program

Launch setup by right click on it and select run as administrator. After launching the setup and providing necessary details you would reach to Server Configuration page . When you reach this page please select startup account for Database Engine services as NT Authority\SYSTEM which is also called as Local System account.

Complete details in [SQL Server Installation Error:Could not find database engine startup handle](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24364.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-find-database-engine-startup-handle-error-during-installation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much, Shanky. I installed and uninstalled many times and was getting very frustrated. Your solution of changing it to NT Authority\SYSTEM worked like a charm.